# Scala: What does << mean?

Tags: scala

I am very new to Scala. I have been asked to implement a feature so I am reading the codebase.

I see the following:

```
def * = (id ~: columns) <>(Account.<<.<<.<<.<<, (Account.unapply _).<<.<<.<<.<<)
```

...but I don't know what `<<.<<.` means, and Google did not gave me any correct result since it is a symbol.

What is this called?

Comment: `<<` is some method defined somewhere. Without any context it's impossible to say more.

Comment: Looks like this comes from a DB library, I'd figure out which one and then ask a new question about it.

Comment: If that's real Scala code then someone should be shot.

Comment: Suggestion: use symbolhound.com when looking for symbols.

Answer (score 5):

<< is just a normal method name in Scala. It seems that in your code you have an Account object defined with a method name <<. And that method returns another object that also has method <<.

You need to look at the help or implementation of the Account.<< method to see what it does. There is nothing special in Scala regarding << that you should be concerned. It is all in your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Load the code in an IDE (e.g. Scala IDE, Ensime or IDEA) and ask the IDE to go to the definition of that `<<`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with Scala, but since it looks like an operator, a quick Google search on "Scala operators" gives the [Scala Operator Cheat Sheet](http://jim-mcbeath.blogspot.in/2008/12/scala-operator-cheat-sheet.html)

This has the following on the `<<` operator:

> << BigInt Leftshift of BigInt
>       << Byte
>       << Char
>       << Int
>       << Long
>       << Short
>       << Buffer Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << BufferProxy Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << Map Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << MapProxy Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << Scriptable Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << Set Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << SetProxy Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << SynchronizedBuffer Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << SynchronizedMap Send a message to this scriptable object.
>       << SynchronizedSet Send a message to this scriptable object.

As for the `.`, I think that would be a way of chaining things.

Hence, one might be able to think of this as the `<<` operator chained multiple times into `Account` etc.

However, `<<` might actually be a method defined somewhere instead of one of the above operators.